# Is there a way to prevent multiple devices from accessing a Google Drive appDataFolder simultaneously?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a app (mobile and desktop version) that synchronizes a user's files to their personal Google Drive. This data is stored in a app-specific folder (appDataFolder)   within the user's account.

Want I want is to put together a mechanism that will prevent a second device (a phone?) from trying to sync data to Google Drive while the first device (maybe a PC?) is already synchronizing data to/from Google Drive. This will help prevent conflicts of all sort that could result.

Is there already a method in place to achieve this goal, or must I put together some sort of hack to achieve it? Or is it even possible to achieve for that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: You dont want them syncing at the same time? or at all?  no there is nothing out of the box to handle either of those issues

Comment: I'd like to prevent multiple devices from syncing at the same time. I've come up with a hack that I know would work. Was just wondering if there was already a built-in solution. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No their isn't nor do I think they would ever bother making something